# .click() on href javascript:void(0) results in undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make javascript auto click on a href link to show more data on the same page.

The Link has a javascript:void(0)

Code block:

```js
document.querySelector("#showMoreHistory256 > a").click();
```

```html
<div id="showMoreHistory256" class="showMoreReplies block" onclick="ecEvent.moreHistory(256, this, 0)
,lk,m"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a></div>
```

But I get the result `Undefined` in the console instead of the execution of the function "show more".

Is the `querySelector` or the `.click()` the wrong command for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and you will not get errors:

```js
var ecEvent = {
moreHistory: function (num,context,depth)
{
alert('The link was clicked programmatically');
}
};
var lk = false, m = false;
document.querySelector("#showMoreHistory256 > a").click();
```

```html
<div id="showMoreHistory256" class="showMoreReplies block" onclick="ecEvent.moreHistory(256, this, 0)
,lk,m"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a></div>
```

Comment: I still get the "undefined" return.

Comment: It must be coming from something else - the above snippet does not produce such error.